# specifying directory for a local .d.ts type file in typescript

Tags: typescript

Over the past few days I have been trying to create a .d.ts for a simple library I found on npm and used in an angular 4 project ([creating typescript .d.ts for third-party library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393529/creating-typescript-d-ts-for-third-party-library)). I was able to create such a declaration file, and I thought that the other problem I had, moving the declaration file to a more appropriate directory, would be fairly simple.

While working on the original problem I had simply created the .d.ts declarations file under `<root>/node_modules/@types` along with the type delcaration files I had downloaded and not created. I had done this because it was fairly clear that my attempts to put the declarations file in another directory were not working, and that seemed a secondary problem. Once I had solved the primary issue I addressed the secondary. I could not find anything to add locations to search for declaration files. I found a setting in `tsconfig.json` that sounded promising,

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types",
  "hmm/@types"
],
```

here with an experimental value, but the value did not do what it sounded like it ought to do. In fact I could remove all the values in the list and not get any different behavior, including for other type libraries. (I have since found a mention that it is used only to resolve directories for `/// <reference=...` directives.)

After a great deal of experimentation and some scanning of the `tsc` code, I stumbled into the realization that if the directory containing additional typescript declarations files included `node_modules/@types`. tsc would find them and treat them as declaration files. In addition to `<root>/npm_modules/@types` I created `<root>/src/npm_modules/@types`, and everything worked as expected. I wasn't happy with the directory name so I tried `<root>/src/@types/npm_modules/@types`, but that failed.

All my builds were through angular-cli `ng`, so it's possible `ng` is secretly creating configuration files that it uses instead of the ones I see, but I don't think that is the case.

Is there any way to configure additional type declaration files for tsc, or to get tsc to recognize certain directories as such? There is a "types" parameter on tsconfig.json, but that seems to mean use *only* those type files, and I would like to use some type files *additionally*. Ideally I think I would like a directory structure similar to: `<root>/@types/library-package-name`. Is this possible?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382951/where-should-i-place-custom-d-ts-files

Answer (score 1):

After some more research and reflection, I believe that putting the ambient declaration file for a third-party library can only be done by putting the file in a directory named "node_modules/@types/ somewhere either off the directory where the third-party library is being used, or off one of its parent directories. If, using an angular 5 example, the component SimpleComponent (in src/app/simple/simple.component.ts) imported a library 'chi-squared-test', the ambient declarations file, chi-squared-test/index.d.ts, could be put in: node_modules/@types/chi-squared-test/index.d.ts (with the installed ones), in src/node_modules/@types/chi-squared-test/index.d.ts, in src/app/node_modules/@types/chi-squared-test/index.d.ts or in src/app/simple/node_modules/@types/chi-squared-test/index.d.ts. I have verified that src/node_modules/@types works. The [documentation from typescript here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) says that the others ought to work too, but I have not tested them.

I have seen posts that suggest to me that one ought to be able to put declaration files not in directories that include "node_modules/@types" by using the "typeRoots" configuration value but I was never able to get that to work. At this point the only way I know which will add ambient type declaration files (.d.ts) is to put them in subdirectories named "node_modules/@types" on the path from directory containing the file that needs the declaration to the project root.

This may be require some work with your .gitignore file. By default I believe it ignores subdirectories that have "node_modules" in the path. In most cases I expect you will want to commit your private library declarations to git, so you will have to adjust your .gitignore to include those directories (a line like "!src/node_modules" should work).